# Closed jquery UI tabs are shown again when new ones are created

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a table (jqGrid) inside one of the jquery ui tabs (the first one). This table has service requests which are identified as links in that table. When the links are pressed, they should open the detailed service request info into a new tab following the first one.

The problem I am having is, when you open one of the service requests in a new tab and close it, resetting the number of tabs into one which hosts the table; Trying to open the service request again will cause the service request info to be opened into a new tab which is equal to the number of previous tabs which were closed previously.

To be precise, if we have `#ui-tab-1`, clicking the service request link inside it, will open the service request info into a `#ui-tab-2`. Now, closing `#ui-tab-2` tab and clicking the another service request link will cause `#ui-tab-2` to be activated along with the new tab `#ui-tab-3`. `#ui-tab-2` hosts the newly opened ticket info.

I am using [scrollableTabs v2.0](http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jst/) plugin/layer to handle the scrollable tabs.

This is the code I am having

```
var $third_l_tabs = $('#table-nav').tabs({
    show: function(event, ui) {
        //we only care about the first tab which hosts the grid.
        if (ui.index == 0) {
            tableToGrid('#' + table_id, {
                defaults: {
                    recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}",
                    emptyrecords: "No records to view",
                    loadtext: "Loading...",
                    pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}"
                },
                loadonce: true,
                height: 'auto'
            });
            jQuery('#' + table_id).trigger('reloadGrid');
        }

        $(ui.panel).on('click', "td[role='gridcell'] a", function(event) {
            //here where the addition of new tab fails.
            $third_l_tabs.tabs('add', this.href, $(this).find('b').text());  
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    },
})
```

And I was checking jQuery ui call stack and I noticed that the `show()` function of the tabs is called for each one of these unrequited closed old tabs!

This is the trace I got in Chrome and as you can see the last 3 lines, show is called again repetitively

```
$.tabs.show() at scp.js:580
$.Widget._trigger() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:581
$.widget._tabify.showTab() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:7195
$.widget._tabify() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:7282    <-- it starts from here
jQuery.extend.dequeue() at jquery-1.7.1.js:2066
jQuery.fn.extend.dequeue() at jquery-1.7.1.js:2098
jQuery.extend.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:658
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:271
jQuery.fn.extend.dequeue() at jquery-1.7.1.js:2097
$.widget._tabify.hideTab() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:7211
$.widget._tabify() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:7278
jQuery.extend.dequeue() at jquery-1.7.1.js:2066
jQuery.fn.extend.dequeue() at jquery-1.7.1.js:2098
jQuery.extend.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:658
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:271
jQuery.fn.extend.dequeue() at jquery-1.7.1.js:2097
$.widget.load() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:7544
$.widget._tabify() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:7285
jQuery.event.dispatch() at jquery-1.7.1.js:3256
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle() at jquery-1.7.1.js:2875
jQuery.event.trigger() at jquery-1.7.1.js:3144
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger() at jquery-1.7.1.js:3781
jQuery.extend.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:658
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:271
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger() at jquery-1.7.1.js:3780
$.xui.tabs.$.extend._create.hiddenOn.right() at jquery.scrollabletab.js:101
jQuery.event.dispatch() at jquery-1.7.1.js:3256
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle() at jquery-1.7.1.js:2875
jQuery.event.trigger() at jquery-1.7.1.js:3144
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger() at jquery-1.7.1.js:3781
jQuery.extend.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:658
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:271
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger() at jquery-1.7.1.js:3780
$.Widget._trigger() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:578
$.widget.add() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:7411
(anonymous function)() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:421
jQuery.extend.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:658
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each() at jquery-1.7.1.js:271
$.widget.bridge.$.fn.(anonymous function)() at jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js:418
$.tabs.show() at scp.js:581
jQuery.event.dispatch() at jquery-1.7.1.js:3256
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle() at jquery-1.7.1.js:2875
```

Any help about what could be the issue would be appreciated. I included the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nawar/fQZnp/) example for this issue.

Comment: code you post a reduced test case with only the faulty code on jsFiddle ?

Comment: Well, If I know where's the faulty code, I would probably know the solution for it :). The code where `$third_l_tabs.tabs('add',...)` is where things go messy.

Comment: Well... Having a reduced "working" demo might help find the problem, and thus, does the `tableToGrid` call relevant here ? I can't say it because I don't know what is it. To locate the problem and fix it it's important to have a whole "working" code, but with at least code as possible, otherwise your code can't be interpreted by others

Comment: The `tableToGrid` is not required here, I tried with it and without it, and in both cases, the problem persist. As for the demo code, it's coming really really soon.

Comment: I added the JSFiddle example. As you can see, when clicking the _Add Tab_ `link` in the first tab, it normally creates the second tabs. But when trying to create the third tab using the same `link` it creates redundant ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `event.stop()` after `event.preventDefault()` did the trick. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/pY3pJ/1/

For some reason the event is being triggered more than once. Add a `event.stop()` to stop the event from being triggered the second time and so forth...

Comment: Well, thanks for the insight. I checked and I found out that there's no such `even.stop()` function. It works because the script fails to continue right there with this error message `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'stop'`. Any way, the solution was by using **`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`**

Comment: `stop()` stops only the current animation and the rest of the animations in the queue are not stopped. `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` should work for you as well - as per the docs, it stops all handlers on an element & implicitly calls `.stopPropagation()` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the insight anyway, you got the bounty, hunter :)